# print signs on two columns table in Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I am trying to print signs in two columns table in classic ASP, ASP file receive the Item-ID's and put them in Array then loop to select signs content from the database, i been able to print in one column, when i tried this code to print in two column i got nothing.
i am not sure what is wrong with the two For statement to loop on records, please help.

```
<%@ LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CodePage = 65001%>
<%
Session.CodePage = 65001
Response.charset ="utf-8"
Session.LCID     = 1033 'en-US
%>
<% Response.CharSet = "UTF-8" %>

<%Dim d1
Dim MyArray
Dim myVal
Dim dept
Dim stype
Dim stemp
d1=request("d1")
dept=request("dept")
stype=request("stype")
stemp=request("stemp")
%>

<%
MyArray=Split(d1,",")

For i=0 to UBound(MyArray)
myVal=Trim(MyArray(i))
Dim objConn
set objConn = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConn.Connectionstring="DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};" &_ 
"DBQ="&server.mappath("\db\Signs - Zone Pricing.mdb")
objConn.Open
Dim strsql
strsql = "SELECT * From " & dept & " where plu='"&myVal&"'" 
Dim objRS
Dim BarcodeData 
BarcodeData = mid(myval,2,11)
Set objRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
objRS.Open strsql, objConn
%>
<html>
<head>
<title>New Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bordercolor="#000000" style="width: 300; height: 125;" class="auto-style1" align="center">
<tr><td>
<%do while not objRS.eof%>
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" width="300" bordercolor="#C0C0C0" id="table1" height="125" background="../images/ServiceSign-Self_3x1.25-1.jpg">
    <tr>
        <td align="right" style="width: 285PX; height: 20px;" colspan="2"></td>
        <%If request("dept") = "Grocery" then %><%IF objRS("UNFI") = "UNFI" then %>
        <td align="right" style="width: 15PX; height: 20px;" class="auto-style2">
        </td><%Else%>
        <td align="right" style="width: 15px; height: 20px;"></td><%End If%><%Else%>
        <td align="right" style="width: 15px; height: 20px;"></td><%End If%>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td  align="right" style="height: 10px; width: 300px;" colspan="4" class="auto-style3"><font face="Neutraface 2 Text Bold" style="font-size: 8pt"><%If request("dept") = "Grocery" then%>
<%=objRS("MISC DESCR")%><%else %><%end if%></font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="height: 5px; width: 300px;" colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="auto-style4">
        <td style="height: 20x;" colspan="3">
        <p align="center" style="width: 300px; height: 20px"><font face="Neutraface 2 Text Bold" style="font-size: 12pt"><%If request("dept") = "Grocery" then%>
<%=objRS("Description")%><%else%><%=objRS("item")%><br><%=objRS("NAME2")%><%end if%></font>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 175px; height:20">    
<img src="<%="http://example.com/IDAutomation/IDAutomationStreamingLinear.aspx?D=" & BarcodeData%>&BH=0.5&H=1.5&S=6&CC=T&FS=8&LM=0.0&TM=0.0&BM=0.0"/>       
</td>

        <td style="width: 75px; height:20; vertical-align:middle" colspan="2" align="right" >
        <font face="Neutraface 2 Text Bold" style="font-size: 16pt"><p align="right">
        <p align="right"><%=Int(objRS("price"))%>.<%=Right(objRS("price")*100,2)%></font><font face="Neutraface 2 Text Demi" style="font-size: 8pt">&nbsp;&nbsp;<%=objRS("unit")%></font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    <tr><td style="width: 300px; height:10" colspan="5" align="right" ></td></tr>
</table>
<%objRS.movenext%>
<%loop%>
</td>
</tr>
<%Next%>
</table>
<br>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p align="center"><font face="Arial" size="2">
<a style="color: #530000" href="signs.asp">Back</a></font></p>
</body>
</html>
```

[The Results looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkaPR.jpg)

[Two Column Result I am looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpZ1f.jpg)

Comment: Show us what the results look like, then explain what is missing.  I will say the formatting of the code is all over the place, ASP code running before the header is called, If/then statements nested in ways that make them visually difficult to pair out to follow each loop.    Random spacing here and there .. that is all aesthetics, but it helps a bit when trying to read the code and spot something in seconds instead of minutes.

Comment: Thank you for your review, I just added a link for a picture of the result.

Comment: The result picture is for one column format, when i add the "For" statements to format into two columns, i get error.

Comment: That does help but I'm still confused as to what you mean by 2 columns.  When you say column, you mean a column from the table in the database?  And so its only getting ONE of them and you need BOTH of them?  For example:
Brand name : Cheddys
Product : Cheddar Cheese

but you are only getting one of those 2 things to print, correct?

Comment: here, I cleaned the code a little:

Comment: What column is missing?  What part of data is missing?  I see it getting Description, Price .. but some are inside of If/then so like "NAME2" might or might not exist depending on what you selected in the form.  There is if/then logic that if it hits certain results it will not get the other information in the script.

Comment: what i meant to two column is format the output in a two column table. i will add another picture of what it should looks like.

Comment: sorry about the confusion, i removed the If statements to simplify, I am getting the right records form the database, I just wanted to format the records into two column table like the second picture I just uploaded.

Comment: Ahh now I understand what you meant.  It looks like its either an Access print setting, or you have to reformat your table tags and move the data around.    You might be able to use a table generator to get the layout you want and then have to copy and paste the code around to get it the way you want.  But see if this link helps:
https://www.rapidtables.com/web/tools/html-table-generator.html

Answer (score 0):

Many assumptions made here, also I think my logic is out in the mod section BUT it does display a two column html table... a little hacky there.

The original code was all over the place, so I reorganised it a bit.
Hopefully this will be enough to get the idea [two column HTML table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmyWD.png)

```
<%@ LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" codepage="65001"%>
<%
SESSION.CODEPAGE = 65001
Response.charset ="utf-8"
Session.LCID = 1033 'en-US
RESPONSE.CHARSET = "UTF-8" %>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>New Page</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<%
DIM D1
DIM MYARRAY
DIM MYVAL
DIM DEPT
DIM STYPE
DIM STEMP
D1=request("d1")
dept=request("dept")
sType=request("sType")
sTemp=request("sTemp")
d1="123456789000,123456789001"
dept="grocery"
sType=request("sType")
sTemp=request("sTemp")
DIM OBJCONN : SET OBJCONN = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
dim strConnectionString : strConnectionString = "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ="&server.mappath("\db\SignsZonePricing.mdb;")
objConn.Connectionstring = strConnectionString
objConn.Open
Dim strsql
Dim objRS
MyArray=Split(d1,",")
dim varUnfi : varUnfi = ""
dim varMiscError : varMiscError = ""
dim varDescription : varDescription= ""
Dim varItem : varItem = ""
dim varName2 : varName2 = ""
dim varPrice : varPrice = ""
dim varUnit : varUnit = ""
dim intRecordcount : intRecordcount = ""
dim tablecount : tablecount = 1
dim intcolumncount : intcolumncount = 1
%>
<TABLE border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" >
            <TR>
        <td valign='top'>
        <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bordercolor="#000000" id="table1">
            <tr>
            <td valign='top'>
        <%
FOR I=0 to UBound(MyArray)
myVal = Trim(MyArray(i))
BarcodeData = mid(myval,2,11)
Set objRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
objRS.CursorLocation = 3
strSql = "SELECT * From " & dept & " where plu='"&myVal&"'"
 objRS.Open strsql, objConn
intRecordcount = objRS.Recordcount

If not objRS.EOF Then
Do Until objRS.EOF
varUnfi = OBJRS("UNFI")
varMiscDescription = objRs("miscDescription")
varDescription = objRS("Description")
vatItem = objRS("item")
varName2 = objRS("NAME2")
varPrice = objRS("price")
varUnit = objRS("unit")
%>
    <TABLE width="300" height="125" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bordercolor="#000000" id="table1">
        <TR>
                    <TD align="right" colspan="2">
                        </TD>
                            <%IF UCASE(DEPT) = ucase("Grocery") then %><%IF UCASE(VARUNFI) = "UNFI" then %>
                                <TD align="right"><%= ucase(varUnfi)%>
                                </TD>
                            <%ELSE%>
                                <td align="right"></td>
                            <%End If%>
                        <%ELSE%>
                        <td align="right"> </td>
                    <%End If%>
                    </TR>
                    <TR>
                        <TD align="right" colspan="3"><FONT fac   e="Arial" style="font-size: 8pt"><%IF UCASE(DEPT) = ucase("Grocery") then         response.write varMiscDescription%></FONT>
                        </TD>
                    </TR>
                    <TR>
                        <TD style="height: 5px; width: 300px;" colspan="3">
                        </TD>
                    </TR>
                    <TR>
                        <TD style="height: 20x;" colspan="3">
                        <FONT face="Arial" style="font-size: 12pt">
                        <%IF UCASE(DEPT) = ucase("Grocery") then
                            Response.Write varDescription & vbCrLf
                        ELSE
                            Response.Write varItem & "<br>" & varName2
                        END IF%>
                        </font>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src="<%="https://www.bcgen.com/demo/linear-dbgs.aspx?D=" &BarcodeData%>&BH=0.5&H=1.5&S=6&CC=T&FS=8&LM=0.0&TM=0.0&BM=0.0"/>
                    </TD>
                        <TD colspan="2" align="right"><%=Int(varPrice)%>.<%=right((varPrice*100),2)%></FONT><FONT face="Arial" style="font-size: 8pt">&nbsp;&nbsp;<%=unit%></FONT>
                        </TD>
                    </TR>
                    <TR>
                        <TD style="width: 300px; height:10" colspan="5" align="right">
                        </TD>
                    </TR>
                </TABLE>
<%
IF (TABLECOUNT MOD (INTRECORDCOUNT/2)) = 0 then
        if INTRECORDCOUNT = tablecount then
            response.write  "</td></tr>"
            exit for
        end if
response.write  "</TD></tr></table></td><td valign='top'><TABLE  border=""1"" cellspacing=""0"" bordercolor=""#000000"" cellpadding=""0""  title=""table"&tablecount&"""><tr><td>" & vbcrlf  & vbcrlf
    else
    response.write  "</TD></tr>" & vbcrlf  & vbcrlf
    response.write  vbtab  & vbtab & "<tr><td valign='top'>" & vbcrlf  & vbcrlf
    end if
tablecount = tablecount + 1
objRS.MoveNext
loop
end if

NEXT
    objRS.Close
Set objRS = Nothing
%>
            </TABLE>    
        </td>
    </tr>
</TABLE>    
<P>&nbsp;</P>
<P align="center"><FONT face="Arial" size="2">
<A style="color: #530000" href="signs.asp">Back</A></FONT></P>
    </body>
</html>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```